# Spring Data JPA : How to use @PathVariable and JPQL

Tags: java, spring-data, jpql

I have two questions about `Spring Data JPA`.

**1st**: How to avoid `@PathVariable` mistakingly recognizing a part of url as a parameter?

The first one is the code about this question.
When I try to access "/sample/insert/", the url is handled as "/sample/{id}/" and I get the error which says like " String 'insert' cannot convert to Integer".

How do I avoid this problem?

**2nd**: Can `JPQL @Query` return an instance?
Please refer to the second code.

For now, the method `insertInto(String name, String mail)` returns int value: the number of Column affected. However, I would like to get the affected column itself as a return value. Can I do this ? Or, should I add another code in a method in a service class to realize that function?

```
@RestController
public class SampleController{
    
    @Autowired
    SampleService sampleService;
    
    @RequestMapping
    public String index(Model model){
       //omitted
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/sample/")
    public String getAllSample(Model model){
       //omitted
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/sample/{id}/")
    public String getSampleById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/{id} ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.getById(id).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sample/insert/")
    public int insert(Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/insert/ ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.create("NewName", "mail@mail.com");
    }
```

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, Integer>{
    
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Sample s ")
    public List<Sample> showAll();
    
    @Query("SELECT s FROM Sample s WHERE id = :id")
    public Sample searchById(@Param("id") Integer id);
    
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO sample (name, mail) VALUES (?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    public int insertInto(@Param("name") String name, @Param("mail") String mail);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you have is having a controller with `{id}` the same as `/sample/insert/`, I suppose because you have `/sample/{id}/` before, he can match the `/sample/insert/` to the first controller.
Not sure if you swapped between the two methods, But I think it won't work as well. As you are confusing spring on which method should work with.

```
    @RequestMapping("/sample/insert/")
    public int insert(Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/insert/ ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.create("NewName", "mail@mail.com");
    }

    @GetMapping("/sample/{id}/")
    public String getSampleById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/{id} ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.getById(id).toString();
    }
```

What you can do to avoid that is, changing to `/sample/get/{id}` will fix the issue for sure.

```
    @GetMapping("/sample/{id}/")
    public String getSampleById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/{id} ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.getById(id).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sample/insert/")
    public int insert(Model model){
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.println(">> accessed: /sample/insert/ ");
        System.out.println("===================");
        return sampleService.create("NewName", "mail@mail.com");
    }
```

for the `insertInto(String name, String mail)`, I believe you can do what you want, but first, you need to know what is the column type. then switch the method to return the type instead of int.

And if you can add more clarification about 2nd question, I will edit the answer to add more details.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Changing the order of the two methods in controller class didn't work, so I rewrote the url "/sample/{id}/" to "/sample/get/{id}/" as you said and it worked successfully. Thank you.

Comment: With regard to 2nd question, I am sorry that my explanation was not enough. I want the method "insertInto(...)" to return Sample instance which is inserted through the method to put out what value is inserted. However, the method's default return value is int type, the number of affected column of table, 1. What I would like to know is "Can this method return the inserted value itself?". I know little about JPQL so I would like to understand what JPQL @Query can. Pardon my pure English.

Answer (score 0):

question one：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzXY4.png)

their request url is same and request method both GET
solution 1: change second request method turn to POST
solution 2: change their request url, like this /smaple/{id}/info

Comment: Thank you for your advise. At last I rewrote the url and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
question 2: SampleRepository extends JpaRepository. JpaRepository defined many methods, include save method. you can code in sampleService
`@AutoWired
 SampleRepository sampleRepository;
 public Sample insert(String name, String email){
     Sample sample = new Sample();
     sample.setName(name);
     sample.setEmail(email);
     int result = this.sampleRepository.save(sample);
     if (result > 0){
       return sample;
     }
    //error
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. As you pointed out, customizing methods in repository class is useful. but I would like to use JPQL @Query. Anyway, you are kind enough to show me your code to resolve this problem. This will also help. Thanks a lot.